# Brightcove ready event

Tags: javascript, brightcove

I have the following code

```
function onBrightcoveReady(event) {
    console.log(event.target || event);
}

experienceModule.getReady(function (result) {
    if (result === true) {
        onBrightcoveReady(experience);
    } else {
        experienceModule.addEventListener(brightcove.api.events.ExperienceEvent.TEMPLATE_READY, 
                                onBrightcoveReady);
    }
});
```

The problem is that sometimes the `onBrightcoveReady` function does not get called. I supposed that it's due to the fact that when the `getReady` method gets called the video is not ready, but in the meantime it gets ready.

If I do double checking it works, but I still don't think it's safe.

```
experienceModule.getReady(function (result) {
    if (result === true) {
        onBrightcoveReady(experience);
    } else {
        experienceModule.getReady(function (result) {
            if (result === true) {
                onBrightcoveReady(experience);
            } else {
                experienceModule.addEventListener(brightcove.api.events.ExperienceEvent.TEMPLATE_READY, 
                                onBrightcoveReady);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the `templateLoadHandler` player parameter for this.

```
<param name="templateLoadHandler" value="onBrightcoveReady" />
```